# Returning pointers from function gives weird numbers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return, function-pointers

Iam trying to get the max number of this array that has numbers from -20 to 30 but it returns weird numbers like this --> 2255667 which is impossible if all is going well.

```
int * ptomx(int a[],int n)
{
  int max=-100;
  int *point;

  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
  {
      if(max<a[i])
      {
        max = a[i];
      }
  }
  point = new int;
 *point = max;
  return point;
}
```

This is what i do in main()

```
int maxTemp;

maxTemp=*(ptomx(a,n));

cout<<"Max temp is:"<<maxTemp;
```

Is it because the pointer in the function is destroyed after the function returns and gives a random number in that memory location. If thats the case it needs to be dereferenced but how?

Comment: You have a memory leak. The returned pointer is never free'd. Why not return the value as a normal, non-pointer, integer?

Comment: Im supposed to do it that way cause im learning to use pointers.

Comment: @AlexMoumoulidis it's not likely that you're supposed to do it *exactly that way* because that particular use of pointers in `main` also leaks the memory.  Conside using `int * maxTemp;` and later `delete maxTemp;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reading values from beyond the end of the array. These values can be **anything** and are what's causing the incorrect results.

```
 for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) 
              //^^
```

Should be changed to

```
 for(int i=0;i < n;i++)
```

Comment: Thx a lot i feel stupid now that iwas trying to fix this for 3 hours and it was so simple.

Comment: @AlexMoumoulidis better to not use pointer at all in your case since you don't really operate on it.

Comment: Better to not use C++ at all in my case and get back to java :P

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop within ptomx is running out of bounds.

Think about it:
If you want every single value, but nothing beyond the last one, do you want to use >=?
If you have 10 values, their actual positions in memory (theoretically) are 0-9. You should only be using > to compensate for this.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

This is what it should look like.